# Anime series about a pair of twins and a doctor

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember watching an anime series in the 2000s, that had as main protagonist a male doctor, that in the past rescued the life of a pair of twins, one of them male, the other female.

As they grew up, the brother became very evil. At some point when the kids were in their early twenties, the whole actual plot came into motion, with both the doctor and the sister setting out on a journey to kill the evil brother, often separated. The hunt did at least for some time go through Germany, the people depicted with huge noses often. The whole storytelling was also working heavily with views into the past as the protagonists hunted the elusive evil brother, showcasing what the evil brother had experienced in the past.

I remember the thing having about... 74 or something episodes, and it was very likely a manga adaption.

Comment: Can you explain how/why this is science fictional or fantastical? As it stands it looks like a thriller but not actually SFF

Comment: @Valorum I believe it had some esper-vibe or something, but I can't remember clearly enough.

Comment: @Valorum can this be moved to Anime/Manga SE?

Comment: @CorvoAttano - [They don't accept (or allow) ID questions.](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/what-wed-like-to-do-about-those-gosh-darn-identification-requests-questions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [*Monster*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_(manga)#Anime) (モンスタ).

It's based in Germany, involves a doctor, twins and murder sub-plots.

> Dr. Kenzo Tenma is a young Japanese brain surgeon, working at Eisler
>   Memorial Hospital in Düsseldorf. Tenma is dissatisfied with the
>   political bias of the hospital in treating patients, and seizes the
>   chance to change things after a massacre brings fraternal twins Johan
>   and Anna Liebert into the hospital. Johan has a gunshot wound to his
>   head, and Anna mutters about killing; Tenma operates on Johan instead
>   of the mayor, who arrived later. Johan is saved, but Mayor Roedecker
>   dies; Tenma loses his social standing. Director Heinemann and the
>   other doctors in Tenma's way are mysteriously murdered, and both
>   children disappear from the hospital. The police suspect Tenma, but
>   they have no evidence and can only question him.

Comment: Assuming this is the correct answer, although the violence is very stylised it's not actually sci-fi or fantasy as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Trish - Based in germany. Involves a doctor. Involves twins. Murder sub-plots. I'd be surprised if this wasn't it but you can always click the wikipedia link to see more info if you feel you need it.l

Comment: I mean, I had some quite specific details... that I can't seem to find on the wikipedia page.

Comment: @Trish - Does the trailer not ring any bells?

Comment: not about the whole stuff I mentioned, which most certainly is not in Ep1...

Comment: There's another (slightly longer) review here; https://www.amazon.com/Naoki-Urasawas-Monster-Box-Set/dp/B002N1AEY6